# Mocking a dependency injection in a trait or a model

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to mock a dependency injection or (would be better) a model relationship.
The model `Place` as a `morphTo` relationship with few modules called `Placeable`.
The modules/placeables can `detect` the proximity of the user. One of them is using a `RemoteGateway` which is specific to the module.

The model that use the `RemoteGateway` has this method

```
use UseRemote;
public function detect(Geolocalisable $geolocalisable): bool
{
    return $this->remote()->recognize($geolocalisable);
}
```

and use this trait

```
trait UseRemote
{
    public static $remote;

    protected static function bootUseRemote()
    {
        self::$remote = app(RemoteGateway::class);
    }

    public function remote(): RemoteGateway
    {
        return self::$remote;
    }
}
```

And of course the RemoteGateway is binded

```
$this->app->bind(RemoteGateway::class, function ($app) {
    return new SomethingRemoteGateway();
});
```

Since `remote()->recognize($user)` depend on an external service, it will mostly always return `false` but for the tests I have to assume, it detect him and should always return true.

I'm now trying to mock this behavior but it doesn't work.

```
    /** @test */
    public function api_show_place_with_registrables: void
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        // mocking Remote Gateway
        $remoteGateway = \Mockery::mock(RemoteGateway::class);
        $remoteGateway->shouldReceive('recognize')
            ->with($user)
            ->andReturn(true);
        $this->app->instance(RemoteGateway::class, $remoteGateway);


        $place = factory(Place::class)->create();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user, 'api')
            ->json('get', "/api/v1/places/{$place->id}");

        dd($response->getContent()); // <-- empty but when I hardcode true in SomethingRemoteGateway it's returning the values
    }
```

But mocking `Placeable` to always return `true` when using `detect` would be much better. In this scenario, my tests wouldn't depend of one of the module specificity.

An alternative I think of, would be to create a FakePlaceable to use in my factories (I'm iterating all the known placeables modules and pick one atm)